# How can I set div on div? - z-index

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with CSS

```
<div id="all-letter2" style="margin-left:40px; margin-right:57px;">
   <div class="inhalt" style="font-size:17px;">
      <div class="line1" style="position: absolute; margin-left:-80px; width:30px; color:gray;   height:10px; font-size:22px; font-weight:470; margin-top:-590px;z-index:10;">_

    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I set `class="line1">` on `class="inhalt"`? z-index?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Consider revising your question.

Comment: If you want `.line1` to have the same index as `.inhalt`, don't do anything with `z-index` in `.line1`

Comment: set line1 position=absolute

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to mimic http://cdn.onextrapixel.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/zindex.jpg with the nested elements you have in your example, then you need to set the parent container to have a position relative. That ensures that the child elements will use it's top and left edges for determining their positions. This [list a part article](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101/) does an excellent job about describing why.
So the html is:

```
<div id="all-letter2">
   <div class="inhalt">
      <div class='line1'></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And your css would be:

```
#all-letter2
{
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:orange;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
.inhalt
{
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left:10px;
}
.line1
{
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```

A visual example is here in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7CL54/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to place `.line1` inside `.inhalt`?

If so, position `.inhalt` relatively, than you can absolute position (which you already have) the `.line1` div.

```
<div class="inhalt" style="font-size:17px; position: relative;">
```

Comment: Not inside. Only `.line1` under `inhalt`.Like here: http://cdn.onextrapixel.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/zindex.jpg

Comment: Position them all absolute.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to set it on top of it just use like you said in the title:

**CSS**

```
.inhalt {
position: relative;
z-index: 1000;
}
.line1 {
position: relative;
z-index: 2000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="inhalt" style="font-size:17px;"></div>

<div class="line1" style="font-size:17px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `.line1` under `inhalt` then you can position them absolute to `all-letter2`.

CSS

```
#all-letter2 {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 57px 0 40px;
}

.inhalt {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:2;
}
.line {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}
```